# Simulating Pinch on Ipad ( ios simulator 4.3 )

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, multi-touch

I am testing multi touch support on Safari mobile. So far, i realized i can simulate a pinch gesture on iphone simulator (just holding option key), however i cannot do the same when i change the device to be the ipad.

Any idea: is that a bug, any settings or it changes the simulation process depending on the device.

Comment: works perfectly fine in iOS simulator here, both on iPhone & iPad simulated versions. I am running XCode 4.2 and AppCode 1.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with the simulator of Xcode 4.3.2: Multi-touch-gestures with the ALT-key work in iPhone-mode, but not in iPad-mode. It cannot be a mistake in my source code, because this is even the case when going to the home-screen in the simulator by pressing *Cmd+Shift+H*.

I found the following work-around: Use *Cmd+2* or *Cmd+3* to reduce size of the iPad-window, then multi-touch-gestures with ALT-key will also work in the iPad-simulator. By pressing *Cmd+1* you can return to the original size of the iPad-simulator.